# Issue with forwarding traffic to Nginx on AWS ALB subpath

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx-config, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using ALB as an ingress to my Kubernetes deployment. I have a rule forwarding traffic on the path `/v2 or /v2/*` to an Nginx container hosting a static react app. Unfortunately, the static assets are not resolving no matter how I configure it, only the root (index.html) is resolving. E.g. /v2/assets/index-6146e9e0.js is not working.

If I change the rule so it forwards traffic to the container if the path is `/ or /*`, then it resolves correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {

 listen 80;
  
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
    
  location /v2/assets/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/;
    expires 1d;
    access_log off;
  }

  # Serve index.html file
  location /v2 {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  # Rewrite absolute URLs to resolve using /v2
  location ~* \.(html|js|ico)$ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    sub_filter 'src="/assets/' 'src="/v2/assets/';
    sub_filter_once off;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is important that the static files are placed in the correct folder. I had placed them in `/usr/share/nginx/html` when they should be placed in `/usr/share/nginx/html/v2/`. In addition I had to change the assets folder to use the correct subpath.

Here is the config that worked for me:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html;

  location /v2/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/v2/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /v2/index.html;

    sub_filter 'src="/assets/' 'src="/v2/assets/';
    sub_filter_once off;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
  }
}
```